# Error displaying SQL post

Tags: php, html, sql

On my page I have a small form with a text box and a submit button and it posts to my SQL server, then I planned on getting back that text and displaying it on the same page, just under a table I have made, but it's not displaying the data from the form input.

I have another page that I made just to test out the code and it was working, but when I put it on homepage.php it doesn't work anymore.

I made a new file called secondary.php and included it above the "echo $template" line but that did not do anything.

Here's the three files I have been working with: http://pastebin.com/utppHc4Y

Here are the error codes I receive: http://pastebin.com/EUUrU2tv

Comment: Stop editing so people can read! GRRRRR

Comment: Instead of code dumping to pastebin, you should narrow your code down to just the basics and add directly to your question, including the error messages. Currently your question is formatted as a 'fix this for me' type of question.

Comment: 1st found error - line#7 of `secondary.php` -> `$query = mysqli_query($selection);`. you are missing your `$dbcon` as the 1st param.

Comment: @Sean I didn't narrow it down because I have a feeling the error is because of the placement of the highlighted piece of code, and the file homepage.php is very confusing because I switch from php to html quite a bit.

Comment: Then you need to clean up you code first. Stop switching from php to html.   A lot of your issues are because you have very messy coding habits.

Comment: 2nd found error - on form submit you have 2 `include('mysql-connection.php');`. This will cause your `Notice: Constant **** already defined` notices. This can easily be avoided by changing your `include('mysql-connection.php');` to `include_once('mysql-connection.php');`.

Comment: @Sean the error you found now displays the posted data, but only one row, not all of them. How can I make it display all of them? I tried switching row[0] to just row, but it gives me an error saying"Array to string conversion in /home/julianbuscema/public_html/secondary.php on line 12", what can I do?

Comment: You are overwriting the value of `$template` on each loop. You need to either `echo` the value right in the loop, or concencate it, ie. `$template .= "anonymous posted: " . $row[0] . "<br>";` (see the `.=`). You may want to initialize the var before the loop to prevent the 1st time saying it is undefined, ie. `$template = "";  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {...`

Comment: @Sean thanks so much man! I fixed everything :) means a lot to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After what @Sean has said, this should not be "fix this for me" So I will be trying to explain why/where you're messing up and you can fix this yourself by learning.

> Error 1:

```
mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
```

This is because you're not saving the mysqli connection. Something like this:

```
$que = mysqli_query($dbcon, $insert)

if (!que)) {

                die('Error processing your post: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
}
```

> Error 2:

```
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, 
null given in /home/julianbuscema/public_html/secondary.php on line 9
```

You are missing your `$dbcon` as the 1st parameter.